# Decide whether the series are absolutely convergent , conditionally convergent, or divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Decide  whether the series are  absolutely  convergent, conditionally convergent, or divergent.

$$a) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(\log n)^{\log n}}{n^a} , a>0$$

$$b) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{[\log n]}}{n}$$ where  [ ]  is  greatest integer  symbol.

My attempt :  the  easiest  way  to  think  about  this  problem is the Leibniz test both $a)$ and $b)$ will be conditionally convergents.

Is  it correct ?

any  hints/solutions

thanks u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one we have that

$$\frac{(\log n)^{\log n}}{n^a}\to \infty$$

indeed by $x=e^y \to \infty$ as $y\ge e^{2a}$

$$\frac{(\log x)^{\log x}}{x^a}=\frac{y^y}{e^{ay}}\ge\frac{e^{2ay}}{e^{ay}}=e^{ay}\to \infty$$

therefore the given series diverges.

For the second one we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{[\log n]}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{1} \frac {1}{n}-\sum_{n=2}^{2} \frac {1}{n}+\sum_{n=3}^{7} \frac {1}{n}-\sum_{n=8}^{20} \frac {1}{n}+\ldots+(-1)^{k+1}\sum_{n=[e^k]}^{[e^{k+1}-1]} \frac {1}{n}+\ldots =\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} a_k$$

that is an alternating sum of terms not convergent to zero and thus it diverges too, indeed as $k\to \infty$ by [**harmonic series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence)

$$a_k=\sum_{n=[e^k]}^{[e^{k+1}-1]} \frac {1}{n}\sim \log (e^{k+1})-\log(e^k)=k+1-k=1$$

Comment: @RushabhMehta Once $a_n \not \to 0$ the series diverges anyway, the$ (-1)^n$ factor is completely useless to conclude here.

Comment: @RushabhMehta For the second one I'm thinking about it, it is not so trivial as the first one.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Now it should be complete. And please revise also your wrong first coment about the $(-1)^n$ term.

Comment: thanks  u @gimusi..one  last confusion how  $y \ge  e^{2a}$ ?

Comment: Recall the y is going to infinity and $e^{2a}$ is some fixed number. It is only a trick to solve the limit by comparison.

Comment: @gimusi..i mean  log(logy)  > 2...is  it correct ??

Comment: @stupid As $y \ge  e^{2a}$ we have $(y)^y\ge (e^{2a})^y=e^{2ay}$. Why are you considering $\log(\log y)>2$?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part note that for $n$ between $e^{k}$ and $e ^{k+1}$, $(-1)^{[\log n]}$ has  a constant sign. Compare $\sum_{[e^{k}]}^{[e^{k}+1]} \frac  1  n$ with the integral of $\frac 1 x $ from $[e^{k}]$ to $[e^{k+1}]$ to see that the sum of the terms from $[e^{k}]$ to $[e^{k+1}]$ does not tend to $0$. Hence the series is divergent.

Comment: sir  how  $e^k $ and$ e^{k+1}$ come ?

Comment: @stupid If $[\ln n]=k$ then $k \leq  \ln n < k+1$. This gives $e^{k} <n <e^{k+1}$.

Comment: sir  thanks  u...