# Is $a_n = (-1)^{[ \log n]}$ is oscillatory sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know  that  $a_n =(-1)^n$ is  oscillatory sequence   as  sequence  osciallate  between $-1$  and $+1 $

I have  some  doubt  in my mind  that   Is  $a_n =  (-1)^{[ \log n]}$ is  oscillatory sequence  ?

Note: []  is "greatest integer less than or equal symbol

Comment: How do you define "oscillatory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_n=1$ if $e^{2k} \leq n <e^{2k+1}$ and $a_n=-1$ if $e^{2k-1} \leq n <e^{2k}$ (for any positive integer $k$) so the sequence oscillates.

Comment: .@KAvi sir    earlier u said me  that  $(-1)^{[\log n]}$  has constant sign.. if that $a_n$ has constant sign  how can  $a_n$ can be   oscaillate

Comment: ..@Kavi  sir see  ur  earlier answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878837/decide-whether-the-series-are-absolutely-convergent-conditionally-convergent

Comment: You are mis-interpreting what I said in that post. In certain ranges $(-1)^{[\log\, n}]$ remains a constant, but that doesn't mean it never changes sign.

Comment: okkss   i mean  $(-1)^{log n ]}$ is contant  that mean  it has  fixed sign implies  sign also  remain constant    ?  isn't  its?

Comment: @jasmine You need to learn to read the entire answers when people give you answers. As OP said, **in certain ranges** $(−1)^{[\log n]}$ remains a constant. That doesn't mean the expression is *always* constant.

Comment: ..@5xum ya u r  right  actually i was thinking  whole range